# In browser FIFO queues using Javascript and AJAX to Web Service

Tags: javascript, ajax, web-services, html, web-worker

I have an existing Adobe AIR application that I have been asked to look into converting to a pure HTML5 app that is browser only.

The application is for scoring images of scanned student work.  The AIR app receives config information about what subject to score and then calls a web service which returns an XML message of individual items to be scored (the server handles things like locking items so only one person can score it at a time).  The app then queues these incoming items and downloads the images for each in the background.  In the foreground, the user is presented with one or more incoming queued items in a form and enters a score for each.  When they submit, it then takes those scores and places them in an outgoing queue.  The outgoing queue is watched and any outgoing messages are then sent to another web service process that records the score on the server.  The experienced users can often score these very quickly depending on the subject (as fast as one per second), so we make heavy use of caching, often storing tens or even hundreds of items locally at a time.

In looking at HTML5 and it's options for localstorage and web workers, I thought this might be possible.  I have done some research, but I am not too experienced with these new HTML5 features.  I see that web workers are isolated and cannot access localstorage or sessionstorage.  I figured I the incoming and outgoing queues could simply be arrays that I push and pop to, but now it's not so clear.  If I need a process to constantly watch the incoming queue (to keep it full) and the outgoing queue (to keep it empty), it seemed like web workers would be ideal.  But they cannot share data or manage the local storage.

Any thoughts or pointers to get me going in the right direction?  I would have fairly tight control over dictating the browser requirements, so we can use the latest and greatest versions.  The web service can also easily be reconfigured to handle JSON instead of XML.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use simple HTML image tags as the queue: Say you have 10 (or n, I use 10 as an example) image tags, all pointing to some `pixel.gif`. On app startup, you set the `src` attributes to the first 10 images - this will result in parallel loading without any need to code something. Use the `onload` event for housekeeping. All these image tags should be hidden.

The moment the first image is done loading, present it to the user by unhiding it. The user will score it - in this moment you hide the image, start an AJAX call to record the vote and unhide the next image.

When the AJAX call returns success, you mark this image tag as free and next in line, and set the `src` attribute to the next image. Rinse and repeat.

The main point is, that by using async HTML constructs such as image load or XmlHttlRequest, you don't need to bother with queues or web workers - in the process creating an app that is compatible even with slightly outdated browsers.

Comment: Interesting, but I am not sure.  Our system has between 1 and 3 "score sections" which have the image and the score form for each image (# of sections depends on subject).  We don't want any scrolling because many users prefer keyboard only.  Once the user has scored images on screen, the all slots are refreshed with the next set.  This gives me some ideas about using HTML elements and showing/hiding.  Not sure if it will keep up with the quantity of items going in and out.  Our users can score simple images at a rate of 1+ per sec -- just keeping their hands on the keypad and going crazy.

Comment: Not wanting to 'promote' my answer, but the showing/hiding is de facto without any delay - you can expand the idea by preparing `<div>` elements with the image AND the form in the background (i.e.: Keep a stockpile), then unhide the next one. There is no scrolling involved, if you use the `display` style property instead (or better additionally to) the `visibility` property

Comment: I guess I will throw together some testing, but I wonder if there would be any performance negatives to building a large number of hidden DOM elements like this (over the other method).  Since I would need a lot (100-200).

Comment: Basically you need a "queue depth" N so, that you can be assured, that the user will never score N images before the next one has loaded - I'd start with 10-20. This will not be a perofrmance problem - I do these things regularily (e.g. preload all forms of a medium-sized application and just show/hide them on demand)

Comment: By not using some queuing, but simply acting on each score click, wouldn't we run into problems with connection limits?  Most browsers limit the number of concurrent requests to the same domain.  Under our current setup, we group messages using XML (download multiple items and send multiple scores).  In this scenario, it's all singles.  That would not only cause a connection limit problem, but bang hard on the server by making it handle lots of little requests instead of fewer bulk requests, no?  By queuing, you wake up every X seconds, see what's waiting to be sent and send one message.

Comment: 1.) On reaching the connection limit, requests will be queued inside the browser - exactly what you want. As long as the server and network connection can sustain the traffic, you will be fine (an you will also be in trouble with AIR if it can't). 2.) On the grouping vs. single request nothing stops you from grouping on the HTML frontend, but I suspect this is not necessary: IIUC each item is an image plus some metadata, you would have to decide if sending the metadata one-by-one really creates relevant server load, the images will be sended 1-by-1 even with AIR